# pi on Ubuntu Calculator?

Tags: calculator, gnome-calculator

Is there a way to get the value `pi` on the Ubuntu Calculator?  I hoped this would work but as you can see it does not:

[image]

Of course I can type in 3.14159 and in > 99% of cases that will be accurate enough, but if there is an actual way to get pi that would be great.

Comment: Isn't it right there (right above `=`, between `-` and `e`)?

Comment: Also `Ctrl`+`P`should work. Check keyboard shortcuts under the hamburger menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's there.

[image]

And here it is in your Question's screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I've never seen pi look like an `n` before, but at least it works

Answer (score -1):

Consider using Qalculate! It has some nice features in addition like being able to convert between units (e.g. add meters, feet and inches) and it knows many mathematical constants and quite some from Physics.